# CoordinatorLayout place layouts on top of eachother

Tags: android, layout, z-index, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` and I want a `FrameLayout` be underneath all the other `Layouts and widgets`. I have tried using `android:layout_below/above` and `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"`, but none of them go above the `FrameLayout` whose `android:id="@+id/container"`.

I think the easiest way would be to put the `FrameLayout` beneath others. For example in javascript there is `Z-index`.

The `FrameLayout` will containt preview from the `Google's Camera2 API`.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToSongList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Song List" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"

        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.724"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playRecord"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="569dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context="com.example.richard.smarttabs.SongPlayer" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Since I am learning, all comments on my style are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood what you are looking for, but I tried to edit it to order a bit all components.

The best way (imo) to order views between each other, is to use a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) which allows you to set `toLeftOf`, `Above`, `Below`, ...

Try to have a look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:context="com.example.richard.smarttabs.SongPlayer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToSongList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Song List" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/songTitle"
        android:background="#c1c1c1"
        >

        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pitchText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="This is centered, above frame"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/playRecord"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#b3b3"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Without a "guide" about what you are looking for, it is hard for me to reproduce the exact expected result, but this should be a start for you. **(I changed some colors and texts to make more evident where each view is)**

In a `RelativeLayout` the Z order is just about which view is written above another, the first in the `XML` is behind, the second is above it and so on.

For any help, just ask freely. I will suggest you to look at some tutorial on youtube, I mostly like [TheNewBoston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y) ones, hope I helped you.

**Little hint**

Try to use the minimum number of exact `dp` value for a `view`, since it is not going to wrap text or fit screen sizes, just test your layout in many sizes and with many texts inside and go for the better result.

ie: you wrote a `TextView` with fixed size of 113dp, but a text like `"this is centered"` was too large and got truncated badly. Use exact dp just when necessary and check many screen sizes for it, (and for `margins/paddings` that in many cases need an exact value)

Comment: Even though some things are changed, it still works, as in I can see the Layouts above and below eachother. Thank you really much. Just one question. I was using CoordinatorLayout because I think that if the screen becomes bigger, everything will lose its place.  Is that also the case with RelativeLayout?

Comment: @kataroty coordinatorlayout is "newer" and it offer good solutions with FAB and NavDrawer, so it might be better. RelativeLayout is pretty much the same, but for bigger screen it all depends on how you write your code. If you hard-code sizes, they will not change. If you use "above, below, ..." and margins, margins will be kept unchanged and the view will stretch. So basically yes, relativeLayout works with bigger screen but it depends on how you write your code, help yourself with the preview and different devices. If needed, consider also creating different layout for different screen sizes

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again since after I placed everything as needed, it started to look very good. Also thank you for your answer about Layouts, you really did help me a lot.